# Want to run WPF application on Asp.net web application.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, iis

I want to run my WPF application on asp.net web application. Actually I have a WPF page.xaml which contain the image viewer, which actually open image and edit it as required.
Now I want to embed that in my Asp.net Web application. I have a asp.net web application user control on which I want that WPF stuff. I research on it on the internet, I find a way that we first publish the WPF application on the IIS server and then past the URL in asp.net web application page iframe. as I follow this below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx#deploying_a_xbap

now I not want to follow this approach. I want an alternate way of this. Is there any way to handle this scenario. If yes then how can we achieve this?

Comment: WPF (and Silverlight for that matter) has a very limited target audience. Fine for intranet / LOB but not for public facing sites (iPad won't be able to render it for example). What is your website / application trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there's a better way: you can use Silverlight (basically it's a C# equivalent to Flash).

Even if Silverlight is quite the same as WPF, there is some differences due to the fact that silverlight is made for web. So you'll have to make some changes to your application.

About integrating it in your page, it seems quite simple:
You can use an `object` html element (as you would do with Flash)
Here are some links about that:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc838145(v=vs.95).aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/host-silverlight-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: no :( we are not using silverlight, we actually using WPF. So is there any way in WPF? I find alot solutions in silverlight but we are not following silverlight.

Comment: Well you should :)! Why aren't you using it? (or can't use it?) Excepts some "security restrictions" it's the same as WPF

Comment: Agree with @ppetrov - If you are using WPF / XAML it should be easy enough to port to Silverlight which is "WPF for the internet" really.

Comment: @ppetrov you right but you can say its our analyser team mistake we actually do alot working in WPF now its very time consuming to go back. Is there any way to do this by keeping our environment in WPF?

Comment: if you're stuck with wpf then the way you tested is the only one I know, sorry

Answer (score 1):

2 years later, a possible answer appears! Maybe someone else will see this and get some use out of it.

I have been hearing rumors that it is possible to run your WPF application in a browser, it's called an XBAP?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I am about to give this a try myself, I'll update this answer with any limitations I find.